# Apps won't sync to jailbroken device from iTunes

Tags: itunes, jailbreak

My iPhone 5s is jailbroken. I want to add some apps to my iPhone from iTunes but all apps don't sync correctly and are dark on my iPhone:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using AppSync to sync the apps, or just redownload them.